# Postgres jsonb_path_exists 'like' functionality for numbers

Tags: postgresql, postgres-14

I currently am trying to implement a search based off one of my postgres tables. The type of the column I am searching is jsonb and I am using jsonb_path_exists like the following

```
select project
from search_table
where jsonb_path_exists(project, '$.** ? (@ like_regex "${searchString}" flag "i")');
```

Where `${searchString}` is a variable being passed in. This is working great when the json is a string type and I get all the results I would expect. However I cannot figure out how to get this to work if the json field is a number type.

For example if I pass in an ID where in the json it is defined as number, something like `id:123456`

I would like to be able to pass in `123` and have the object with a value like `123456` being picked up. Basically a 'like' but against a number type. If the id was `id:'123456'` it works fine, but since it is a number the current implementation won't pick it up. Is there a way to use `jsonb_path_exists` where I can pick up both string and number types with a 'like' type expression?

My current workaround is casting the whole thing to text and searching like that

```
select project 
from search_table
where UPPER(project::text) like UPPER('%${searchString}%')
```

However, this just seems like an unnecesary step and I would prefer to just search the json values with `jsonb_path_exists`. I am using postgres 14.7, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

***UPDATE with min example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dmspgdev.zz_yache_test
(
    project_id numeric(19,0),
    project jsonb
)

insert into dmspgdev.zz_yache_test
values (1,'{"id":123456, "data":"test1"}');

insert into dmspgdev.zz_yache_test
values (2,'{"id":789323, "data":"search works with string"}');

-- works because data is string
select project
from dmspgdev.zz_yache_test
where jsonb_path_exists(project, '$.** ? (@ like_regex "search" flag "i")');

-- No results because id is number
select project
from dmspgdev.zz_yache_test
where jsonb_path_exists(project, '$.** ? (@ like_regex "456" flag "i")');
```

Comment: can you please add your create table with data as text so that we get a [mre]

Comment: Pattern matching applies only to strings, a number (data type) cannot be compared in that manner unless it's cast to varchar or text data types.

Comment: @nbk Added min example. Thanks

Comment: @PepeNO so does this mean my current workaround is really the right way to go, or can there be casting done within jsonb_path_exists functionality? Thanks

Comment: Your query work, as "456" is  a string and the text also you can search for it https://dbfiddle.uk/sv7pFfHL

Comment: @nbk in your example it works because you added 456 to data field where I just wanted it based off the id field which is number. I need it to pick it off just the id since the search is looking through all fields in the json. So I would need entry with id: 123456 to work, recreated here: https://dbfiddle.uk/cy3ooqRv

Comment: then make the id also a string, it shouldn't make a difference https://dbfiddle.uk/YOLGWwzj

Comment: @DougYachera could be like your workaround because castings are not allowed inside the JSON path expression.

Comment: if you still need the number without converting it, you can add a text Number as further value

Comment: @nbk Unfortunately I do not have control as to just making the ID a string and there are many more fields like it in the real project object, I just picked a simple example to demonstrate the point. I appreciate you taking the time to look into, it looks like I may have to go route Pepe is suggesting  or just stick with my workaround

Comment: Hey @DougYachera, did you find a way to do this? I have the same scenario and would like to know what was the best solution you found, thanks.

Comment: @carloscastillo I never found exactly what I wanted. For now I stuck with casting everything to text and searching that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select project 
from dmspgdev.zz_yache_test 
where project->>'id' ~~ '%${searchString}%' 
or project ->>'data' ~~* '%${searchString}%';
```

using the operator ilike "~~*" case insensitive LIKE and dividing maters for each of your json fields. Without the need of casting types since the operator "->>" gets the json object field as text.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but excepting as answer since it seems like what I really wanted to do is not possible. This answer at least limits the search to the field values and not values and fieldnames like my workaround